# how to find the last update time of a SQLite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, time

I want to know how to find the last time when my database was updated.
I am doing an application on android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get the lastModified date off the SQLite database file itself. Use the emulator and DDMS file explorer if you don't know its location.

For example:

```
File dbpath = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
long lastModified = dbpath.lastModified();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the database file is in SD card, you could look at the file attributes for it.

If it is internal (default), there is no way afaik. You may just store the last modification in a different place whenever you update the db.

Answer (score 0):

While this is doable in theory (the database is just a file), it's a rather common task in database development. You normally have a rather small amount of tables that are capable of changing independently, you store a datetime field in them, you update the field using insert/updates, and when it's time to check for the last change date, you query for the `max()` of that datetime field.